# Cannot read property 'top' of undefined of link href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm basing an active class for links in a navigation via scroll.

```
    function onScroll(event){
        var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        $('.sticky-navigation-posts a').each(function () {
            var currentLink = $(this);
            var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
            console.log(refElement);
            if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
                $('.sticky-navigation-posts .title-wrapper .post-title a').removeClass("active");
                console.log('yes!');
                currentLink.addClass("active");
            } else {
                currentLink.removeClass("active");
                console.log('no!');
            }
        });
    }
```

When i `console.log(refElement)`, the element is logged. However If i `console.log(refElement.position().top)`, this error is thrown `Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`. I've been debugging for a while now and cant figure it out. Any ideas? I've also tried wrapping `refElement` in a `$()`.
 All of this code is wrapper in a `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Are you sure it is visble? `jQuery does not support getting the position coordinates of hidden elements or accounting for borders, margins, or padding set on the body element.`

Comment: The elements are on the page. Not hidden.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you do a `console.log` of `refElement.is(':visible')`

Comment: Yeah @Thesane should be correct. I haven't pay enough attention to your code...

Comment: @anolsi Okay it is NOT visible. but how when i can clearly see it on the page...

Answer (score 1):

ok I got what do you mean now. However, it is working fine for me. Not sure what where do you have a problem?

I added `console.log(refElement.position().top);` and it is logging properly to the console and even the desired behavior is working!? http://jsfiddle.net/thesane/Dxtyu/3133/

Comment: I've tried that. This example does it differently. http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/

Comment: Ok, I don't where did you get your example, but I don't think `position()` method is available for `attributes`. It is only available for `elements` or `tags`. If you have a fiddle, show me

Comment: jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141

Comment: is using `currLink` achieve the expected output ?http://jsfiddle.net/thesane/Dxtyu/3132/

Comment: what do you expect to happen exactly?

Comment: the same thing the jsfiddle link i sent you does

Comment: The last edit on that answer isn't working for you, @JoshSpears ?